# Styling individual cells in a listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, styling

On the internet I found many examples of styling a complete column or complete row in a listview.

I need to be able to dynamically style individual cells in the listview. How can I access the properties of individual items in a row?

Comment: That's going to be difficult/problematic, simply because, as the name suggests, the ListView control is all about viewing LISTS, and ummm, one specific cell is seen as "just a data point in a collection". If you're trying to extend a ListView into a spreadsheet you're setting yourself up for failure. If what you want IS a spreadsheet then I suggest you search for a Windows Forms Spreadsheet Control. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: @corlettk, why would you want to use WinForms control in a WPF application? I think that's always only the last resort, if there's not other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't need this. Assuming you are using `GridView`, you should be able to use `CellTemplate` or `CellTemplateSelector` of your `GridViewColumn`s.

If you really want to access specific cells, I think there is no clean way, you'd be better using `DataGrid` (from .Net 4 or WPF toolkit for .Net 3.5). With that, you can do something like this:

```
((TextBlock)datagrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(m_specificItem)).Background = Brushes.Red
```

Comment: I originally thought of doing it with a DataGrid, but I read that the difference between a ListView and a DataGrid is all about editing. I don't need any editing capabilities. I only need to present data in a nice way. I guess the DataGrid could be causing a lot of overhead. Right? Jeff

Comment: I tried a DataGrid, but the following code gives an error: ((TextBlock)dgFinancialData.Columns[1].GetCellContent("ID")).Backgr­ound = Brushes.YellowGreen; Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm having 3 columns and 7 rows.

Comment: @Jeff, the parameter to `GetCellContent()` has to be an item that is in the grid's `Items` collection (to which you can assign also by setting the `ItemsSource` property).

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a finite number of properties in your data objects that you want to use to style your items, you can create data templates and styles, and use data triggers to switch between them. I've used something like this to alter the appearance of data objects in a list based on if they are "active/inactive" and to create a collapsed/expanded version of the object based on whether it's selected or not.

You can also use converters (built-in or custom) to get some effects easily. For example, I used a built-in boolean to visibility converter to hide/unhide the combobox/textblock in my `TaskSelectedTemplate` based on if the object's `IsActive` member.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TaskSelectedTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        ...
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0 0 4 0"
                BorderThickness="0" 
                CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActiveToColor}">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding Path="IsActive"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsPaused"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="0 2">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TaskTypes}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Type}"
                      Text="{Binding Type}"
                      Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource InvBoolToVis}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" task"/>
        </StackPanel>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TaskNotSelectedTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        ...
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0 0 4 0"
                BorderThickness="0" 
                CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActiveToColor}">
                    <Binding Path="."/>
                    <Binding Path="IsActive"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsPaused"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Type}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                   TextAlignment="Right">
                <Run Text="{Binding Length.TotalMinutes, StringFormat='0', Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text=" min"/>
            </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                   TextAlignment="Right">
                <Run Text="{Binding TimesPerformed, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text=" tasks"/>
            </TextBlock>            
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <!--this part changes the selected item highlight color-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border Name="Border">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                Property="Background" Value="#2000BFFF">
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!--this part causes selected task to expand-->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TaskNotSelectedTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TaskSelectedTemplate}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For more complex scenarios, you might want to look at [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). I've never used it, but it seems like it might be ideal if you've got a lot of data templates to juggle.